# How do I troubleshoot "Fatal error during the API action" (Response Code 6)

Tags: play-billing-library

I have implemented the Play Billing Library, and it's overall been very successful - but it seems that a few calls to make a purchase (or get available products) fail w/ a Response Code 6 (Fatal error during the API action).

No other information is provided, and most calls succeed, so this isn't a problem where I've completely done something wrong. How do I troubleshoot this issue? Is there a way to know what causes this error?